# Spyder 5.1.5 does not activate environment properly, leads to DLL load failures

Tags: windows, spyder

I just installed Spyder 5.1.5 using the standalone installer.
I connected it to my existing conda environment (located in an unusual location: C:\envs\py37) following the simple instructions here:
http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-spyder-faqs-ref

The Ipython console starts up correctly (version is correct), but when I try to import `numpy` lots of errors show up. The same thing happens when I try to import `cv2` or `pyarrow`, which are all packages that depend on some enclosed DLLs.
I know these packages work fine in the environment, if it's activated properly, but looks like Spyder is failing to do so.
I tried adding the `Lib` and `DLLs` sub-paths to the PYTHONPATH manager in Spyder (and restarted console) but still same issues. See screenshot below.

For comparison, VS Code works fine with this environment (because it activates prior to running anything in the python console).
The activation VS code does is:
`C:\envs\py37\Scripts\activate && conda activate py37`
Which cover all the bases.

[EDIT]: I was finally able to force this to work if I do the following in the command prompt:

```
call C:\envs\py37\Scripts\activate
python "C:\Program Files\Spyder\Spyder.launch.pyw"
```

This is NOT really a good solution and further re-enforces the idea that spyder does NOT activate the environment, so I'm hoping there's a better way.

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think the cause of this problem could be that you don't have `conda` in your `PATH` (the default and most common option). We do have activation scripts for Windows and Mac/Linux, but they assume that.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba yes, you are correct. However this is NOT the default option when installing (ana/mini)conda. You have to click on that additional setting (which the installer itself does NOT recommend). So In all honesty, I think it's a bad assumption to expect this and VS Code rightly knows this.

Comment: Well, I don't know how VSCode does its magic, but if we don't detect `conda` in your system, we can't use it to activate your env, sorry.